# Echo Server doesn't echo

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, echo

I'm trying to write an echo client server but I do not get any response from the server. Don't know where my mistakes are.
I've seen some examples on the internet. Some just use InputStream/OutputStream but I decided to use BufferedReader and PrintWriter - does this make any big differences?

Server side:

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Server server = new Server();   
    server.runServer(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
}

private void runServer(final int port){
    ServerSocket serversckt = null;
    Socket socket = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;

    try{
       serversckt = new ServerSocket(port);
       socket = serversckt.accept();
       System.out.println("Request from client accepted!");


       in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
       out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

       String str;
       while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
           System.out.println(str);
           out.println(str);
           out.flush();
       }
    }
     catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }   

}
}
```

Client side:

```
public class Client{

public static void main(String[] args){
    Client client = new Client();   
    client.runClient(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), args[1]);
}

private void runClient(final int port, final String hostname){
    Socket sckt = null;
    try{
        sckt = new Socket(hostname, port);
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sckt.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sckt.getOutputStream(), true);

        String str;
        while((str = stdIn.readLine()) != null){
            out.println(str);
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
        }

    } catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that `while((str = in.readLine()) != null)` in the server is a blocking call, so it will be `null` on the first read and it will then terminate the server. Maybe someone else has more knowledge about the `BufferedReader` and if it blocks there.

Comment: Can you really call an echo server that doesn't echo an *echo* server?

Comment: @thatotherguy That's most likely the point: read from the console, send that to the server and read its "echo". @OP `System.out.println(in.readLine());` may also don't block, so it will read "nothing" since the server is offline (read my first comment) or doesn't had the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem. I added the missing imports and the final `}` in Client.java, compiled, and ran the server and client in different terminals.

Client:

> $ java Client 2000 localhost
>   foo
>   foo
>   bar
>   bar

Server:

> $ java Server 2000
>   Request from client accepted!
>   foo
>   bar

Every time I wrote something in the client window, it was echoed back to me, and the same line showed up on the server.

Comment: I found my mistake (it was eclipse)! The code is correct indeed!